# How to save page state using cookie(s)?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

So I have a night mode feature on my website, below is just a brief example of what the code looks like on my website. I was wondering how would I be able to save the state of the page, so that it stays dark / light after a page refresh. Do I do this with a cookie? I've never implemented cookies into any of my websites before and could really use some help.

Here is the HTML with the buttons on it to activate the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<title>Ryan Simms</title>

</head>

<body>
<script src="scripts/lightSwitch.js"></script> <!-- Loads Script -->

<footer>
    <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOff"></button>
    <button type="button" id="lightSwitchOn"></button>
</footer> <!-- Closes Footer -->

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);

function handleDocumentLoad() {

//Variable
var offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOff
var onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn"); //Targets div with ID lightSwitchOn
var style = document.getElementById("pageStyle"); //Targets stylsheet
offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
onSwitch.style.display = "none";

//Event Listener
offSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOff); //When clicked this action is performed
onSwitch.addEventListener("click", lightsOn); //When clicked this action is performed

//Function
function lightsOff() { /*This changes the background colour to black and makes text white*/
    style.setAttribute('href', 'css/darkStyle.css');
    onSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn Off Night Mode";
    onSwitch.style.display = "inline";
    offSwitch.style.display = "none";
}

function lightsOn() { /*This changes the background colour to a white and makes text black*/
    style.setAttribute('href', 'css/lightStyle.css');
    offSwitch.innerHTML = "Turn On Night Mode";
    onSwitch.style.display = "none";
    offSwitch.style.display = "inline";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set cookies:

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
```

You can also specify the path that the cookie should belong to. The default is the current page.

```
documenet.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue; path=/folder/";
```

Read cookies:

```
var cookies = document.cookie;
```

This will set the value of `cookies` to a long string arranged like:

```
"cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2"
```

Note that you cannot access cookies from other sites, and document.cookie will only return the cookies for the current domain.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp has a good cookie tutorial.

---

Here's an example of how you might do the parsing:

```
var sugar = document.cookie;
// finds the lights cookie
var start = sugar.indexOf("lights=");
// if there is a light cookie
if (start != -1) {
    // moves the start index to the value of the cookie
    start += "lights=".length;
    // finds the end of the lights cookie value
    var end = sugar.indexOf(";", start);
    var cookieValue;
    // extract the value of the lights cookie
    if (end == -1) {
        cookieValue = sugar.substring(start);
    } else {
        cookieValue = sugar.substring(start, end);
    }

    if (cookieValue == "on") {
        lightsOn();
    } else {
        lightsOff();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused what would be the example in my case?

Comment: In your `lightsOn()` function you would set a cookie like: `document.cookie = "lights=on";`  And in your `handleDocumentLoad()` function you would parse the `document.cookie` string to see if it contains a cookie "lights" with the value "on". If so, you'd call the `lightsOn()` function.

Comment: Okay I added a cookie in my lights on function and my lights off function, but I have no idea about parsing them to check what they contain, and after that what would I do if they contained on or off? It's really confusing me, I'm sorry, I am new to cookies

Comment: @Ryan Upated answer with an example.

Comment: Okay I did this but when I refresh the page it still goes back to normal

Comment: And if I try doing off instead of on it gives me errors on all the lines inside the lightsOff function

Comment: Do you have an else statement after the `if (cookieValue == "on") {...}` for when the cookie value is "off"?

Comment: I used your if statement and changed it to off instead but gave me errors